# Unable to execute any processing tool in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, tools

I am new to QGIS and want to learn some basic tools. However, after software  installation I cannot execute any tool from the processing toolbox. All the tools is giving me the same error:

```
The following layers were not correctly generated. You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

The only tools which I could successfully perform so far are *Contour tool* and *Clip raster by extent tool* from *Raster - Extraction* tab.

Below is the example log for Line Smoothing tool:

```
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Line smoothing' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'ITERATIONS' : 10, 'LINES_IN' : 'D:/Tanaka/Ilandag_Contours.gpkg', 'LINES_OUT' : 'C:/Users/Acer/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_9da93462bf9f4ec8af00f5e24a02cd1e/efcdce475006430596a69e483d14fb24/LINES_OUT.shp', 'METHOD' : 2, 'PRESERVATION' : 10, 'SENSITIVITY' : 3, 'SIGMA' : 2 }

shapes_lines "Line Smoothing" -LINES_IN "C:/Users/Acer/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_9da93462bf9f4ec8af00f5e24a02cd1e/148495a26d744cb1957234b468b4f7c5/LINES_IN.shp" -METHOD 2 -SENSITIVITY 3 -ITERATIONS 10 -PRESERVATION 10.0 -SIGMA 2.0 -LINES_OUT "C:/Users/Acer/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_9da93462bf9f4ec8af00f5e24a02cd1e/efcdce475006430596a69e483d14fb24/LINES_OUT.shp"

C:\Users\Acer\Documents>set SAGA=D:/QGIS/apps\saga-ltr

C:\Users\Acer\Documents>set SAGA_MLB=D:/QGIS/apps\saga-ltr\modules

C:\Users\Acer\Documents>PATH=D:\QGIS\apps\qgis-ltr\bin;D:\QGIS\apps\grass\grass76\lib;D:\QGIS\apps\grass\grass76\bin;D:\QGIS\apps\Python37;D:\QGIS\apps\Python37\Scripts;D:\QGIS\apps\qt5\bin;D:\QGIS\apps\Python27\Scripts;D:\QGIS\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32\WBem;D:\QGIS\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32;D:\QGIS\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs;;D:/QGIS/apps\saga-ltr;D:/QGIS/apps\saga-ltr\modules

C:\Users\Acer\Documents>call saga_cmd shapes_lines "Line Smoothing" -LINES_IN "C:/Users/Acer/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_9da93462bf9f4ec8af00f5e24a02cd1e/148495a26d744cb1957234b468b4f7c5/LINES_IN.shp" -METHOD 2 -SENSITIVITY 3 -ITERATIONS 10 -PRESERVATION 10.0 -SIGMA 2.0 -LINES_OUT "C:/Users/Acer/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_9da93462bf9f4ec8af00f5e24a02cd1e/efcdce475006430596a69e483d14fb24/LINES_OUT.shp"
____________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 2.3.2 (32 bit)

____________________________
library path: D:\QGIS\apps\saga-ltr\modules\
library name: shapes_lines
library : Lines
tool : Line Smoothing
author : V. Wichmann, J. Engels (c) 2014
processors : 2 [2]
____________________________

Load shapes: C:/Users/Acer/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_9da93462bf9f4ec8af00f5e24a02cd1e/148495a26d744cb1957234b468b4f7c5/LINES_IN.shp...


Parameters

Lines: LINES_IN
Smoothed Lines: Smoothed Lines
Method: Gaussian Filtering
Sigma: 2.000000

Length of the Gaussian window: 15

Error: executing tool [Line Smoothing]

C:\Users\Acer\Documents>exit
Execution completed in 15.05 seconds
Results:
{'LINES_OUT': 'C:/Users/Acer/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_9da93462bf9f4ec8af00f5e24a02cd1e/efcdce475006430596a69e483d14fb24/LINES_OUT.shp'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>C:/Users/Acer/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_9da93462bf9f4ec8af00f5e24a02cd1e/efcdce475006430596a69e483d14fb24/LINES_OUT.shp</li></ul>You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

I am using QGIS version 3.4.10-Madeira long term release. 
Looking forward for your help!

Comment: Really any? Try some from non-SAGA trees please, do those also not work?

Comment: Also try seeing if they work when you save to a non-temporary work space.

Comment: The same problem for the GRASS split tool: 

The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>D:/Tanaka/Split.gpkg</li></ul>You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.

Comment: However, could execute GDAL Aspect tool. It seems like I could perform the tools dealing with vector data. Really don't understanda what can be the problem..